# iOS NSURLSession Get Request JSON always showing outdated data

Tags: json, ios7, nsurlsession

I have the following doubts about the JSON data returned from using both "GET" versus "POST" request. In the following URL [JSON DATA](http://www.ebuynus.com/public_html/v/1021-x4RlPr0d.json), the data is not always updated based on the server changes (eg: database). For example, if I delete all the suggestion records from the database when I had 3 previously, it still returns 3 suggestion records in my JSON response body when I call dataTaskWithRequest.

However, if I change to POST, then the JSON response body will always be updated with the actual records from the server. In my server code (Using CakePHP), I did not check for post or get data. Actually, it was intended to be a GET method, but for some reason, only POST method seems to always fetch the most up to date data from JSON as opposed to GET.

Below is my code from my iOS client, but I'm not too sure if its very useful. I was wondering if there is a cache issue for GET request as opposed to POST request? However, I tried disabling cache for `NSURLSessionConfig` but it had no impact.

```
config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
```

The code base is below:

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/v/%@.json", hostName, apptIDHash];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

    if (!error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
            NSError *jsonError;
            NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
            [self printJSONOutputFromDictionary:jsonObject];
            if (!jsonError) {
                block(jsonObject, nil);
            }
            else{
                block(nil, jsonError);
            }
        }
        else{
            NSError *statusError = [self createServerUnavailableNSError:httpResp];
            block(nil, statusError);
        }
    }
    else{
        block(nil, error);
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

In the above code fragment, the JSON body is always showing outdated data.

I really want to understand the issue, and would really appreciate if anyone could explain this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following request header:

```
[req addRequestHeader:@"Cache-Control" value:@"no-cache"];
```

I encountered the same problem as you and adding the above code solved the problem for me.

Taken from [ASIHTTPRequest seems to cache JSON data always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251867/asihttprequest-seems-to-cache-json-data-always)